# Why does my AC compressor stop after a while?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Our air conditioner appears to be experiencing a strange problem. After one to two hours the air compressor would shut down or fail to kick in. It'd reset itself after turning off for a couple of hours.

I thought the old 45uF capacitor was bad, as it was hot to the touch when the compressor went down. The measured capacitance on the old was actually good. Strangely enough, the new capacitor is also experiencing the same issue now.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

EDIT: It's a split system. Model Panasonic CS  W24DKR.

Comment: Including the brand/model of all equipment might be appropriate. Otherwise, you'll get general suggestions for a vague question.

Comment: @FreeMan Sorry it's a Panasonic split system. CS W24DKR.

Comment: Are you in the southern hemisphere?

Comment: @Huesmann Yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

Your condensation line may be blocked.  Most systems have a switch that shuts the system down when water is detected to be backed up in the drain.

You may be experiancing this with a partial blockage. When the water in drain line drops low enough the system will work again, until the condensation backs up again and activates the overflow safety switch.

Comment: But the start capacitor feels hot to the touch. Would a blockage cause the capacitor to heat up?

Answer (score 0):

1. The capacitor helps the motor start; while it is running, it is out of the circuit. It would *not* be a cause if the motor runs.
2. If the refrigerant were low, or overfilled, it could cause motor overheating. Single-piece window air conditioners are unlikely to have this issue, since they're welded in one piece, but central AC and split AC have couplings that occasionally leak.
3. As mentioned, it could be a slow drain line issue.

Comment: About the motor overheating, what I can tell is the capacitor overheating though. Would low refrigerant cause the capacitor to overheat?

Comment: If the *capacitor* is hot, then it could be the motor centrifugal switch is welded closed.See https://www.aces.edu/blog/topics/farming/start-and-run-capacitors-for-electric-motors/